# Not understanding AngularJS function naming conventions

Tags: angularjs

I see in multiple places that functions in AngularJS begin with uppercase (but not always).  In JohnPapa's style guide

https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#named-vs-anonymous-functions

he shows the following.  What I don't get is why Dashboard starts with uppercase and logger is lowercase.  shouldn't those be the same?

```
/* recommended */

// dashboard.js
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('Dashboard', Dashboard);

function Dashboard() { }

// logger.js
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('logger', logger);

function logger() { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what he says [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#controller-names):

> Use consistent names for all controllers named after their feature. Use UpperCamelCase for controllers, as they are constructors.
>
> Why?: UpperCamelCase is conventional for identifying object that can be instantiated using a constructor.

Comment: thanks, just got to that part of the style guide. https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#controller-names  Is a factory the only thing in angular that is not a constructor? (confused a little here)

Comment: Factories/services are singletons, that's probably the login behind John's reasoning. He suggests directives should use prefixed UpperCamelCase.

Comment: (I think you mean "logic" and not "login".  Not sure how to edit that or if I can)

Comment: Ah, mechanical typing, sorry. No, we can't edit comments after 5 minutes, but it's not that relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

controllers begin with an uppercase and services with a lowercase. Good practice to put include the words controller/service as in:

```
 angular.module('app', [])
   .controller('DashboardController', [function Dashboard() { 
   }])
   .factory('loggerService', [function (){
   }]);
```